# Add dynamic text to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, text, textview, addition, android-relativelayout

I want to create a "Enter your name"-page (for the highscore) for my Android-game but I’m experiencing some problems.
I want it to look like this:

> You have reached (=enthst1)
>
> .........here’s the score..............
>
> points! (=enthst2)
>
> Please type in your name to save your score! (= enthst3)
>
> ........EditText for name.....
>
> Back (=button) ................... Enter (=button)

But I don’t seem to be able to add the score (int) to my ContentView!

Here’s the code:

Java in "onCreate":

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_hs);

layo = new RelativeLayout(this);
MySco = new TextView(this) ;


Back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enthsre1);
Back.setOnClickListener(this);

Enter =(Button)findViewById(R.id.enthsok1);
Enter.setOnClickListener(this);

Eingabe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;

Texta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enthst1) ;
Textb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enthst2) ;
Textc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enthst3) ;

Intent intentk = getIntent();
kontro = intentk.getStringExtra("from").equals("MainActivity") ;

score = 0 ;

if(kontro == false){
score = punkteRechnen(tuleb, le0leb, le1leb, le2leb) ; //calculate the score
} else {
score = 10 ;
}

scoint = "" + score ;

MySco.setText(scoint) ;
MySco.setTextColor(Color.WHITE) ; 
MySco.setTextSize(20);

/*I know that this will throw me an IllegalStateException (the specified child already has a parent)
layo.addView(Texta) ;
layo.addView(MySco) ;
layo.addView(Textb) ;
layo.addView(Textc) ;
layo.addView(Eingabe) ;
layo.addView(Back) ;
layo.addView(Enter) ;
*/
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".EnterHSActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/enthst1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/enthst1a"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/enthst2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/enthst1b"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/enthst3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/enthst1c"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enthsre1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:text="@string/retour" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enthsok1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:text="@string/allesklar" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/enthsre1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/enthsok1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/enthst3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textColorLink="@color/red" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, how do I add the score to my layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add a view to a layout if it is already a child of that layout. When you call setcontentview your XML layout is inflated and all those views are created and added to your view hierarchy.

I would add the MySco text view to your layout XML then call findviewbyid to get it. I would avoid dynamically adding views. You can always create a view that is hidden and then show it later to get a similar effect.

Here is the modified / stripped down code for your onCreate method.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_hs);
MySco = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
Intent intentk = getIntent();
kontro = intentk.getStringExtra("from").equals("MainActivity") ;

score = 0 ;

if(kontro == false){
score = punkteRechnen(tuleb, le0leb, le1leb, le2leb) ; //calculate the score
} else {
score = 10 ;
}

scoint = "" + score ;

MySco.setText(scoint) ;
MySco.setTextColor(Color.WHITE) ; 
MySco.setTextSize(20);
```

In your layout add this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"  />
```

Comment: My problem is that I won't know the exact score before calling punkteRechnen(), so I can't add it to the layout-xml and put the value in Strings.xml beforehand. I'd love to use the layout-xml but I don't know if it's even possible to add a value to the Strings.xml while the app is already running.

Comment: That is fine. After calling punkteRechnen, call setText on the text view, just like you have done. Your problem in the code above is that The score text view has not been added to your layout. Let the layout .xml and setContentView do all that hard stuff. You just need to update the text after the text view has been created. You need to remove the 2 calls where you allocate things "= new xxx", and replace those with findViewById. then simply update the text in the view returned by findViewById.

Comment: Thanks, thanks, thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted to do (but unfortunately, I didn't know how) and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call addView on textA, textB, etc, because they're already existant in your XML file, and are already children of a view. Instead you should make an empty RelativeLayout in your XML file, then create textA, etc, with new TextView(), and add those to the layout instead.

Comment: I know, I can't do that because of the exception. But when do I have to set the ContentView? If I leave it where it is and lateron add content, the new views won't show up, will they?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help you.

Add the textview in relative layout to add score on layout.

```
MySco.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300,300);
layo.addView(MySco);
```

Comment: I think, I have to set layo as ContentView or it won't show up but if I do, the other textviews, the edittext and the buttons won't be there.

Comment: First define linearlayout in your layout.xml file and set textview in that linearlayout. To add textview in linearlayout you can use my above code.

Comment: An additional LinearLayout within the RelativeLayout? Unfortunately I still have to set layo as ContentView and I have to do this before "Enter.setOnClickListener(this);" or it won't work (already tried copying "setContentView(layo);" to the end but it only output some errors).